# Change Identical Code Strings in Multiple, Separate Files in One Command

Tags: unix, find-and-replace

How can I change strings of code in multiple HTML documents which are all identical, to something else? How can I change this:

File A: `code1`
File B: `code1`
File C: `code1`
...

Into this:

File A: `code2`
File B: `code2`
File C: `code2`
...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a simple for loop and the `sed` editor. Assuming you are using BASH, the command would be:

```
for i in *.html; do
sed -i s/'foo bar'/'bar baz'/g $i
done
```

This will substitute every occurance of the string `foo bar` with the string `bar baz` in every html file in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sed` to make replacements to all HTML files in the current directory:

```
sed -i s/code1/code2/g *.html
```

Or, if you also need to make the replacement to HTML files in subdirectories:

```
find -name '*.html' -exec sed -i s/code1/code2/g '{}' \;
```